# How do I remove a portion of a line of text in C#

Tags: c#

I need some assistance removing a portion of a line of text from a file.  Example:

let's say I have output from a dir listing like so:

```
 Directory of C:\Data\Junk

03/12/2014  08:35 AM    <DIR>          .
03/12/2014  08:35 AM    <DIR>          ..
03/05/2014  05:36 PM               397 junk.xml
03/05/2014  05:36 PM               397 more_junk.xml
```

and my goal is to turn it into the following:

```
 Directory of C:\Data\Junk

.
..
junk.xml
more_junk.xml
```

I know how to do this using editors if I have an expected string to remove, but am unable to figure out how to do this dynamically.  Alternatively - is there a way to detect that if the first portion of the line is a date, to then remove X characters (where X in this case would take me to the start of the file names)?

Thanks in advance for any help here!

Comment: In Command Prompt (DOS) you can get file names and directory names only using `dir /b` where `b` is for bare format. You can get a txt file like `dir /b > mytextfile.txt` and you will get only file/directory names without time stamps

Comment: Yes, and the code is fairly straightforward. You basically already described it, you just need to turn it into C# instead of English. But why would you want to. Why not obtain a list of files from a directory using built in .NET framework methods?

Comment: the `System.IO` namespace is MUCH easier to use.

Comment: Or in case of writing mainly command line tool with small amount of C# code consider to use PowerShell instead of CMD to get objects directly instead of string representation and inline C# code.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just list all files using Directory.GetFiles ?

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Data\Junk", "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

and then just format it as you wish, for example

```
Console.WriteLine(".");
Console.WriteLine("..");
foreach(string f in files)
{
  Console.WriteLine(file);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know the length of how much of the string you want to discard (which above appears to be 40 characters), you can do

`yourString.Substring(40)`

to get the remainder of the line.

However, the advice of the comments is sound--you probably shouldn't need to process this particular case of strings in the first place.

Comment: Consider to show `string part = yourString.Substring(...)`  - depending on background one can think that `Substring` modifies the original string...